# Форки на Github'е

Tags: git, github

Есть репа https://github.com/aaa/test, допустим юзер bbb делает форк  https://github.com/bbb/test, после чего юзер aaa сделает в родительскую репу коммит.

Подскажите возможно ли теперь юзеру bbb получить изменения в свою репу? или надо удалять свой форк и делать заново?

Comment: Нет, форк удалять не надо. Можно втянуть изменения в форки. См. например мой [проект][1].

[1]:https://github.com/gecube/opencaesar3/network

Answer (score 7):

```
git remote add upstream git@github.com:aaa/<имя репозитория>.git
git pull upstream master
```

Здесь вместо upstream можно дать исходному репозиторию любое имя по своему желанию.

Comment: Ну, вообще можно через веб-интерфейс делать пулл реквест.

Comment: @gecube: Кому, самому себе от автора исходного? Насколько я знаю, можно только наоборот.

Comment: Ну, предположим, что я - автор (изначальный), тогда я могу через веб-интерфейс сделать pull request из форка, над которым работает другой человек, и втянуть его изменения к себе. Он может сделать то же самое (втянуть мои изменения), но запросить через эту функцию, чтобы обновился его репозиторий я не могу - в этом Вы правы.

Comment: P.S. естественно, что при этом обновление репозиториев произойдет на гитхабе. А локально изменения можно будет получить при следующем fetch/pull

Comment: @gecube: А в чём вы видите разницу "изначальный" и "форк"? Все репозитории на github равнозначны. Виртуальное дерево, история того, кто у кого сфоркал существует только для информационных целей. Вы не можете зайти в чужой репозиторий, не имея туда push прав и создать там в ui pull request.

Answer (score 2):

bbb должен выполнить:

```
git remote add aaa git://github.com/aaa/test.git
git fetch aaa
git rebase aaa/master
git push origin master --force
```

Это если aaa и bbb оба работают на ветке `master`, если нет - заменить соответствующе.

Answer (score 1):

Все просто, может получить, bbb нужно будет сделать чекАут ааа - пулл и мэрдж, если надо.. 
вернутся в свой брэнч и продолжать работу